# What is the best practice between StatefulWidget with const constructor and a StatelessWidget with a non const constructor

Tags: flutter

I'm using `ValueNotifier` which is non constant value. There two way to create a widget with it, I'm wondering which one is the best:

First way, in a `StatelessWidget` with a non constant constructor :

```dart
class NonConstConstructor extends StatelessWidget {
  NonConstConstructor({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  final notConstValue = ValueNotifier(null);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ValueListenableBuilder(
      valueListenable: notConstValue,
      builder: (_, __, ___) => const SizedBox.shrink(),
    );
  }
}
```

Second way, in a `StatefulWidget` with a `const` constructor :

```dart
class ConstConstructor extends StatefulWidget {
  const ConstConstructor({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ConstConstructor> createState() => _ConstConstructorState();
}

class _ConstConstructorState extends State<ConstConstructor> {
  final notConstValue = ValueNotifier(null);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ValueListenableBuilder(
      valueListenable: notConstValue,
      builder: (_, __, ___) => const SizedBox.shrink(),
    );
  }
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

A common practice is to not use Stateful Widget unnecessarily, Use it when you need to update the state of the screen. That being said, the `ValueListenableBuilder` widget is already a stateful widget. So using that in a stateless or stateful is not gonna make any difference.